# How to make Utf-8

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, meta

I have set my coding on website using `<meta charset="Utf-8">` I have it right written, so if there is a mistake, it is not in my website. Now.. It does not work. I think it is because of website coding is set by "windows-1208" or something like that. But I can not find out how to fix this, because is defined by my computer... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`<meta charset="Utf-8">` tells the browser to display the page in UTF-8. But if you used an **other encoding in your editor** (e.g. windows-1208 or so) and saved your html page in that encoding, the page won't be displayed correctly.

Make sure, you saved your file in the same encoding as you declared in the meta tag.

To fix it, open the html document in e.g. Notepad++, choose in the menu «Encoding» «Encode in UTF-8 without BOM»

[image]